# Python regular expression for string with the following format

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble making a Regex to find a string matching the format of:

```
'One or more numeric digits///Any combination of alphanumerics and non-alphanumerics///Any combination of alphanumerics and non-alphanumerics///Any combination of alphanumerics and non-alphanumerics'
```

A more specific example would be:

```
'Number of transactions///Total Revenue///Product name///Cost of Supplies'
```

Which would look something like:

```
'1002///1502.34///Coca-Cola-12.Oz///902.23'
```

There are no whitespaces in the strings.

I've tried the Regex: `r'\d+///\d+.\d+///\w+///\d+.\d+'`
The problem is that for the `\w+` section because it can sometimes contain non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a character class in between the words to allow what characters should be matched. In this case you could add a `.` and a `-`

Note to escape the dot to match it literally.

```
\d+///\d+\.\d+///\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*///\d+\.\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k56BoT/1)

Other options could be using only the character class or if you don't want to allow `/` in between, a negated character class:

```
\d+///\d+\.\d+///[\w.-]+///\d+\.\d+
\d+///\d+\.\d+///[^/\n]///\d+\.\d+
```